Bounding a plane by a box in asymptote
I am building a software in Asymptote to draw a plane which has been clipped by a rectangular prism. I have successfully implemented this for cases where the plane's normal vector has at least one component which is zero.
However, when all components are non-zero, my attempted logic is producing visibly inaccurate results. I was wondering if anyone know how to implement such software, or could lead me in the right direction.
The goal is to find the points of intersection, and then sort them so that they make a convex closed shape.
I would like to achieve this where it automatically sorts the points, and uses the minimal amount of them. Currently, they are unsorted, and all eight are traversed.
Here is the relevant code snippet:
unitsize(1cm);

import three;
import graph3;

void draw_plane(
    triple normal_vector
    ,triple point_on_plane
    ,real xmin = -5
    ,real xmax = 5
    ,real ymin = -5
    ,real ymax = 5
    ,real zmin = -5
    ,real zmax = 5
    ,pen thecolor = white
    ,real theopacity = 0.3
    ,bool drawthebox = false
) {

    if (drawthebox) {
        draw(box((xmin,ymin,zmin), (xmax,ymax,zmax)));
    }
    
    real a = normal_vector.x;
    real b = normal_vector.y;
    real c = normal_vector.z;
    real d = dot(normal_vector, point_on_plane);

    real x(real y, real z) {
        return (((d)-((b)*(y))-((c)*(z)))/(a));
    }

    real y(real x, real z) {
        return (((d)-((a)*(x))-((c)*(z)))/(b));
    }

    real z(real x, real y) {
        return (((d)-((a)*(x))-((b)*(y)))/(c));
    }

    //  the final case
    if (a!=0 && b!=0 && c!=0) {
        triple xminymin1 = (xmin,ymin,z(xmin,ymin));
        triple xminymin2 = (xmin,ymin,z(xmin,ymin));
        if (zmax<z(xmin,ymin)) {
            xminymin1 = (x(ymin,zmax),ymin,z(x(ymin,zmax),ymin));
            xminymin2 = (x(ymax,zmax),ymax,z(x(ymax,zmax),ymax));
            if (x(ymin,zmax)>xmax || x(ymin,zmax)<xmin) {
                xminymin1 = (xmin,y(xmin,zmax),z(xmin,y(xmin,zmax)));
            }
            if (x(ymax,zmax)>xmax || x(ymax,zmax)<xmin) {
                xminymin2 = (xmin,y(xmin,zmax),z(xmin,y(xmin,zmax)));
            }
        }
        if (z(xmin,ymin)<zmin) {
            xminymin1 = (x(ymin,zmin),ymin,z(x(ymin,zmin),ymin));
            xminymin2 = (x(ymax,zmin),ymax,z(x(ymax,zmin),ymax));
            if (x(ymin,zmin)>xmax || x(ymin,zmin)<xmin) {
                xminymin1 = (xmin,y(xmin,zmin),z(xmin,y(xmin,zmin)));
            }
            if (x(ymax,zmax)>xmax || x(ymax,zmax)<xmin) {
                xminymin2 = (xmin,y(xmin,zmin),z(xmin,y(xmin,zmin)));
            }
        }

        // Intersection at xmax, ymin
        triple xmaxymin1 = (xmax, ymin, z(xmax, ymin));
        triple xmaxymin2 = (xmax, ymin, z(xmax, ymin));
        if (zmax < z(xmax, ymin)) {
            xmaxymin1 = (x(ymin, zmax), ymin, z(x(ymin, zmax), ymin));
            xmaxymin2 = (x(ymax, zmax), ymax, z(x(ymax, zmax), ymax));
            if (x(ymin, zmax) > xmax || x(ymin, zmax) < xmin) {
                xmaxymin1 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmax), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmax)));
            }
            if (x(ymax, zmax) > xmax || x(ymax, zmax) < xmin) {
                xmaxymin2 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmax), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmax)));
            }
        }
        if (z(xmax, ymin) < zmin) {
            xmaxymin1 = (x(ymin, zmin), ymin, z(x(ymin, zmin), ymin));
            xmaxymin2 = (x(ymax, zmin), ymax, z(x(ymax, zmin), ymax));
            if (x(ymin, zmin) > xmax || x(ymin, zmin) < xmin) {
                xmaxymin1 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmin), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmin)));
            }
            if (x(ymax, zmin) > xmax || x(ymax, zmin) < xmin) {
                xmaxymin2 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmin), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmin)));
            }
        }

        // Intersection at xmax, ymax
        triple xmaxymax1 = (xmax, ymax, z(xmax, ymax));
        triple xmaxymax2 = (xmax, ymax, z(xmax, ymax));
        if (zmax < z(xmax, ymax)) {
            xmaxymax1 = (x(ymin, zmax), ymin, z(x(ymin, zmax), ymin));
            xmaxymax2 = (x(ymax, zmax), ymax, z(x(ymax, zmax), ymax));
            if (x(ymin, zmax) > xmax || x(ymin, zmax) < xmin) {
                xmaxymax1 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmax), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmax)));
            }
            if (x(ymax, zmax) > xmax || x(ymax, zmax) < xmin) {
                xmaxymax2 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmax), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmax)));
            }
        }
        if (z(xmax, ymax) < zmin) {
            xmaxymax1 = (x(ymin, zmin), ymin, z(x(ymin, zmin), ymin));
            xmaxymax2 = (x(ymax, zmin), ymax, z(x(ymax, zmin), ymax));
            if (x(ymin, zmin) > xmax || x(ymin, zmin) < xmin) {
                xmaxymax1 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmin), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmin)));
            }
            if (x(ymax, zmin) > xmax || x(ymax, zmin) < xmin) {
                xmaxymax2 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmin), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmin)));
            }
        }

        // Intersection at xmin, ymax
        triple xminymax1 = (xmin, ymax, z(xmin, ymax));
        triple xminymax2 = (xmin, ymax, z(xmin, ymax));
        if (zmax < z(xmin, ymax)) {
            xminymax1 = (x(ymin, zmax), ymin, z(x(ymin, zmax), ymin));
            xminymax2 = (x(ymax, zmax), ymax, z(x(ymax, zmax), ymax));
            if (x(ymin, zmax) > xmax || x(ymin, zmax) < xmin) {
                xminymax1 = (xmin, y(xmin, zmax), z(xmin, y(xmin, zmax)));
            }
            if (x(ymax, zmax) > xmax || x(ymax, zmax) < xmin) {
                xminymax2 = (xmin, y(xmin, zmax), z(xmin, y(xmin, zmax)));
            }
        }
        if (z(xmin, ymax) < zmin) {
            xminymax1 = (x(ymin, zmin), ymin, z(x(ymin, zmin), ymin));
            xminymax2 = (x(ymax, zmin), ymax, z(x(ymax, zmin), ymax));
            if (x(ymin, zmin) > xmax || x(ymin, zmin) < xmin) {
                xminymax1 = (xmin, y(xmin, zmin), z(xmin, y(xmin, zmin)));
            }
            if (x(ymax, zmin) > xmax || x(ymax, zmin) < xmin) {
                xminymax2 = (xmin, y(xmin, zmin), z(xmin, y(xmin, zmin)));
            }
        }

        draw(
            surface(
                xminymin1 -- xminymin2 --
                xmaxymin1 -- xmaxymin2 --
                xmaxymax1 -- xmaxymax2 --
                xminymax1 -- xminymax2 --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
    }
}

void draw_plane_test() {
    draw_plane(
        (2,2,2)
        ,(-3,4,1)
        ,thecolor=red
        ,drawthebox=true
    );
    draw_plane(
        (-2,-3,1)
        ,(-3,4,1)
        ,thecolor=green
    );
    draw_plane(
        (-2,-3,1)
        ,(3,3,-1)
        ,thecolor=blue
    );
}

draw_plane_test();


Here is the complete code, to give an idea of what I'm trying to do: (It can be  ran here: http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/, or locally)
unitsize(1cm);

import three;
import graph3;

void draw_plane(
    triple normal_vector
    ,triple point_on_plane
    ,real xmin = -5
    ,real xmax = 5
    ,real ymin = -5
    ,real ymax = 5
    ,real zmin = -5
    ,real zmax = 5
    ,pen thecolor = white
    ,real theopacity = 0.3
    ,bool drawthebox = false
) {

    if (drawthebox) {
        draw(box((xmin,ymin,zmin), (xmax,ymax,zmax)));
    }
    
    real a = normal_vector.x;
    real b = normal_vector.y;
    real c = normal_vector.z;
    real d = dot(normal_vector, point_on_plane);

    real x(real y, real z) {
        return (((d)-((b)*(y))-((c)*(z)))/(a));
    }

    real y(real x, real z) {
        return (((d)-((a)*(x))-((c)*(z)))/(b));
    }

    real z(real x, real y) {
        return (((d)-((a)*(x))-((b)*(y)))/(c));
    }

    if (a==0 && b==0 && c==0) {
        draw(
            surface(
                (xmin,ymin,zmin) -- 
                (xmax,ymin,zmin) --
                (xmax,ymax,zmin) --
                (xmin,ymax,zmin) --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
        draw(
            surface(
                (xmin,ymin,zmax) -- 
                (xmax,ymin,zmax) --
                (xmax,ymax,zmax) --
                (xmin,ymax,zmax) --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
        draw(
            surface(
                (xmin,ymin,zmin) -- 
                (xmax,ymin,zmin) --
                (xmax,ymin,zmax) --
                (xmin,ymin,zmax) --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
        draw(
            surface(
                (xmin,ymax,zmin) -- 
                (xmax,ymax,zmin) --
                (xmax,ymax,zmax) --
                (xmin,ymax,zmax) --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
        draw(
            surface(
                (xmin,ymin,zmin) -- 
                (xmin,ymax,zmin) --
                (xmin,ymax,zmax) --
                (xmin,ymin,zmax) --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
        draw(
            surface(
                (xmax,ymin,zmin) -- 
                (xmax,ymax,zmin) --
                (xmax,ymax,zmax) --
                (xmax,ymin,zmax) --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
    }

    // yz planes
    if (a!=0 && b==0 &&c==0) {
        if (xmin<=d/a && d/a<=xmax) {
            draw(
                surface(
                    (x(ymin,zmin),ymin,zmin) --
                    (x(ymax,zmin),ymax,zmin) --
                    (x(ymax,zmax),ymax,zmax) --
                    (x(ymin,zmax),ymin,zmax) --
                    cycle
                )
                ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
            );
        }
    }

    // xz planes
    if (a==0 & b!=0 & c==0) {
        if (ymin<=d/b && d/b<=ymax) {
            draw(
                surface(
                    (xmin,y(xmin,zmin),zmin) --
                    (xmax,y(xmax,zmin),zmin) --
                    (xmax,y(xmax,zmax),zmax) --
                    (xmin,y(xmin,zmax),zmax) --
                    cycle
                )
                ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
            );
        }
    }

    // xy planes
    if (a==0 && b==0 & c!=0) {
        if (zmin<=d/c && d/c<=zmax) {
            draw(
                surface(
                    (xmin,ymin,z(xmin,ymin)) --
                    (xmax,ymin,z(xmax,ymin)) --
                    (xmax,ymax,z(xmax,ymax)) --
                    (xmin,ymax,z(xmin,ymax)) --
                    cycle
                )
                ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
            );
        }
    }

    // y of x planes (invariant over z)
    if (a!=0 && b!=0 && c==0) {
        real xylower = xmin;
        if (ymax < y(xmin,0)) {
            xylower = x(ymax,0);
        }
        if (y(xmin,0) < ymin) {
            xylower = x(ymin,0);
        }

        real xyupper = xmax;
        if (ymax < y(xmax,0)) {
            xyupper = x(ymax,0);
        }
        if (y(xmax,0) < ymin) {
            xylower = x(ymin,0);
        }

        if (!(xylower<xmin || xmax<xylower) && !(xyupper<xmin || xmax<xyupper)) {
            draw(
                surface(
                    (xylower,y(xylower,0),zmin) --
                    (xyupper,y(xyupper,0),zmin) --
                    (xyupper,y(xyupper,0),zmax) --
                    (xylower,y(xylower,0),zmax) --
                    cycle
                )
                ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
            );
        }
    }

    // z of x planes (invariant over y)
    if (a!=0 && b==0 && c!=0) {
        real xzlower = xmin;
        if (z(xmin,0)<zmin) {
            xzlower = x(0,zmin);
        }
        if (zmax<z(xmin,0)) {
            xzlower = x(0,zmax);
        }

        real xzupper = xmax;
        if (z(xmax,0)<zmin) {
            xzupper = x(0,zmin);
        }
        if (zmax<z(xmax,0)) {
            xzupper = x(0,zmax);
        }

        if (!(xzlower<xmin || xzlower>xmax) && !(xzupper<xmin || xzupper>xmax)) {
            draw(
                surface(
                    (xzlower,ymin,z(xzlower,0)) --
                    (xzupper,ymin,z(xzupper,0)) --
                    (xzupper,ymax,z(xzupper,0)) --
                    (xzlower,ymax,z(xzlower,0)) --
                    cycle
                )
                ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
            );
        }
    }

    // z of y planes (invariant over x)
    if (a==0 && b!=0 && c!=0) {
        real yzlower = ymin;
        if (z(0,ymin)<zmin) {
            yzlower = y(0,zmin);
        }
        if (zmax<z(0,ymin)) {
            yzlower = y(0,zmax);
        }

        real yzupper = ymax;
        if (z(0,ymax)<zmin) {
            yzupper = y(0,zmin);
        }
        if (zmax<z(0,ymax)) {
            yzupper = y(0,zmax);
        }

        if (!(yzlower<ymin || yzlower>ymax) && !(yzupper<ymin || yzupper>ymax)) {
            draw(
                surface(
                    (xmin,yzlower,z(0,yzlower)) --
                    (xmin,yzupper,z(0,yzupper)) --
                    (xmax,yzupper,z(0,yzupper)) --
                    (xmax,yzlower,z(0,yzlower)) --
                    cycle
                )
                ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
            );
        }
    }

    //  the final case
    if (a!=0 && b!=0 && c!=0) {
        triple xminymin1 = (xmin,ymin,z(xmin,ymin));
        triple xminymin2 = (xmin,ymin,z(xmin,ymin));
        if (zmax<z(xmin,ymin)) {
            xminymin1 = (x(ymin,zmax),ymin,z(x(ymin,zmax),ymin));
            xminymin2 = (x(ymax,zmax),ymax,z(x(ymax,zmax),ymax));
            if (x(ymin,zmax)>xmax || x(ymin,zmax)<xmin) {
                xminymin1 = (xmin,y(xmin,zmax),z(xmin,y(xmin,zmax)));
            }
            if (x(ymax,zmax)>xmax || x(ymax,zmax)<xmin) {
                xminymin2 = (xmin,y(xmin,zmax),z(xmin,y(xmin,zmax)));
            }
        }
        if (z(xmin,ymin)<zmin) {
            xminymin1 = (x(ymin,zmin),ymin,z(x(ymin,zmin),ymin));
            xminymin2 = (x(ymax,zmin),ymax,z(x(ymax,zmin),ymax));
            if (x(ymin,zmin)>xmax || x(ymin,zmin)<xmin) {
                xminymin1 = (xmin,y(xmin,zmin),z(xmin,y(xmin,zmin)));
            }
            if (x(ymax,zmax)>xmax || x(ymax,zmax)<xmin) {
                xminymin2 = (xmin,y(xmin,zmin),z(xmin,y(xmin,zmin)));
            }
        }

        // Intersection at xmax, ymin
        triple xmaxymin1 = (xmax, ymin, z(xmax, ymin));
        triple xmaxymin2 = (xmax, ymin, z(xmax, ymin));
        if (zmax < z(xmax, ymin)) {
            xmaxymin1 = (x(ymin, zmax), ymin, z(x(ymin, zmax), ymin));
            xmaxymin2 = (x(ymax, zmax), ymax, z(x(ymax, zmax), ymax));
            if (x(ymin, zmax) > xmax || x(ymin, zmax) < xmin) {
                xmaxymin1 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmax), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmax)));
            }
            if (x(ymax, zmax) > xmax || x(ymax, zmax) < xmin) {
                xmaxymin2 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmax), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmax)));
            }
        }
        if (z(xmax, ymin) < zmin) {
            xmaxymin1 = (x(ymin, zmin), ymin, z(x(ymin, zmin), ymin));
            xmaxymin2 = (x(ymax, zmin), ymax, z(x(ymax, zmin), ymax));
            if (x(ymin, zmin) > xmax || x(ymin, zmin) < xmin) {
                xmaxymin1 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmin), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmin)));
            }
            if (x(ymax, zmin) > xmax || x(ymax, zmin) < xmin) {
                xmaxymin2 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmin), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmin)));
            }
        }

        // Intersection at xmax, ymax
        triple xmaxymax1 = (xmax, ymax, z(xmax, ymax));
        triple xmaxymax2 = (xmax, ymax, z(xmax, ymax));
        if (zmax < z(xmax, ymax)) {
            xmaxymax1 = (x(ymin, zmax), ymin, z(x(ymin, zmax), ymin));
            xmaxymax2 = (x(ymax, zmax), ymax, z(x(ymax, zmax), ymax));
            if (x(ymin, zmax) > xmax || x(ymin, zmax) < xmin) {
                xmaxymax1 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmax), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmax)));
            }
            if (x(ymax, zmax) > xmax || x(ymax, zmax) < xmin) {
                xmaxymax2 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmax), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmax)));
            }
        }
        if (z(xmax, ymax) < zmin) {
            xmaxymax1 = (x(ymin, zmin), ymin, z(x(ymin, zmin), ymin));
            xmaxymax2 = (x(ymax, zmin), ymax, z(x(ymax, zmin), ymax));
            if (x(ymin, zmin) > xmax || x(ymin, zmin) < xmin) {
                xmaxymax1 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmin), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmin)));
            }
            if (x(ymax, zmin) > xmax || x(ymax, zmin) < xmin) {
                xmaxymax2 = (xmax, y(xmax, zmin), z(xmax, y(xmax, zmin)));
            }
        }

        // Intersection at xmin, ymax
        triple xminymax1 = (xmin, ymax, z(xmin, ymax));
        triple xminymax2 = (xmin, ymax, z(xmin, ymax));
        if (zmax < z(xmin, ymax)) {
            xminymax1 = (x(ymin, zmax), ymin, z(x(ymin, zmax), ymin));
            xminymax2 = (x(ymax, zmax), ymax, z(x(ymax, zmax), ymax));
            if (x(ymin, zmax) > xmax || x(ymin, zmax) < xmin) {
                xminymax1 = (xmin, y(xmin, zmax), z(xmin, y(xmin, zmax)));
            }
            if (x(ymax, zmax) > xmax || x(ymax, zmax) < xmin) {
                xminymax2 = (xmin, y(xmin, zmax), z(xmin, y(xmin, zmax)));
            }
        }
        if (z(xmin, ymax) < zmin) {
            xminymax1 = (x(ymin, zmin), ymin, z(x(ymin, zmin), ymin));
            xminymax2 = (x(ymax, zmin), ymax, z(x(ymax, zmin), ymax));
            if (x(ymin, zmin) > xmax || x(ymin, zmin) < xmin) {
                xminymax1 = (xmin, y(xmin, zmin), z(xmin, y(xmin, zmin)));
            }
            if (x(ymax, zmin) > xmax || x(ymax, zmin) < xmin) {
                xminymax2 = (xmin, y(xmin, zmin), z(xmin, y(xmin, zmin)));
            }
        }

        draw(
            surface(
                xminymin1 -- xminymin2 --
                xmaxymin1 -- xmaxymin2 --
                xmaxymax1 -- xmaxymax2 --
                xminymax1 -- xminymax2 --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
    }
}

void draw_plane_test() {

    // (a==0 && b==0 && c==0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,0,0)
    //     ,(0,0,0)
    //     ,thecolor=blue
    //     ,theopacity=0.1
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );

    // (a!=0 && b==0 && c==0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (-2,0,0)
    //     ,(-1,-1,-1)
    //     ,thecolor=red
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (3,0,0)
    //     ,(3,2,1)
    //     ,thecolor=red
    // );

    // (a==0 && b!=0 && c==0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,2,0)
    //     ,(2,-2,2)
    //     ,thecolor=blue
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,-3,0)
    //     ,(1,5,2)
    //     ,thecolor=blue
    // );

    // (a==0 && b==0 && c!=0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,0,1)
    //     ,(2,-2,2)
    //     ,thecolor=green
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,0,-2)
    //     ,(1,5,1)
    //     ,thecolor=green
    // );

    // (a!=0 && b!=0 && c==0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (1,2,0)
    //     ,(3,3,3)
    //     ,thecolor=red
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (-1,2,0)
    //     ,(3,3,3)
    //     ,thecolor=red
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (20,-3,0)
    //     ,(-3,-2,-4)
    //     ,thecolor=red
    // );

    // (a!=0 && b==0 && c!=0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (-2,0,3)
    //     ,(0,0,0)
    //     ,thecolor=green
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (-4,0,-3)
    //     ,(2,2,2)
    //     ,thecolor=green
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (4,0,30)
    //     ,(-2,3,-2)
    //     ,thecolor=green
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );

    // (a==0 && b!=0 && c!=0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,-2,3)
    //     ,(0,0,0)
    //     ,thecolor=blue
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,-4,-3)
    //     ,(2,2,2)
    //     ,thecolor=blue
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,4,30)
    //     ,(3,-2,-2)
    //     ,thecolor=blue
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );

    // (a!=0 && b!=0 && c!=0)
    draw_plane(
        (2,2,2)
        ,(-3,4,1)
        ,thecolor=red
        ,drawthebox=true
    );
    draw_plane(
        (-2,-3,1)
        ,(-3,4,1)
        ,thecolor=green
    );
    draw_plane(
        (-2,-3,1)
        ,(3,3,-1)
        ,thecolor=blue
    );
}

draw_plane_test();


Surely this must have been done before! Yet I cannot find a resource, even for scripting this in other languages.

I have used ai to find a working solution:
unitsize(1cm);

import three;
import graph3;

// Function to sort points based on the angle with the centroid
triple[] sort_points(triple[] points) {
    triple centroid = (0, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
        centroid += points[i];
    }
    centroid /= points.length;

    real[] angles;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
        angles.push(atan2(points[i].y - centroid.y, points[i].x - centroid.x));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; ++j) {
            if (angles[i] > angles[j]) {
                real temp_angle = angles[i];
                angles[i] = angles[j];
                angles[j] = temp_angle;

                triple temp_point = points[i];
                points[i] = points[j];
                points[j] = temp_point;
            }
        }
    }

    return points;
}

void draw_plane(
    triple normal_vector,
    triple point_on_plane,
    real xmin = -5,
    real xmax = 5,
    real ymin = -5,
    real ymax = 5,
    real zmin = -5,
    real zmax = 5,
    pen thecolor = white,
    real theopacity = 0.3,
    bool drawthebox = false
) {
    if (drawthebox) {
        draw(box((xmin, ymin, zmin), (xmax, ymax, zmax)));
    }

    real a = normal_vector.x;
    real b = normal_vector.y;
    real c = normal_vector.z;
    real d = dot(normal_vector, point_on_plane);

    real x(real y, real z) { return (d - b * y - c * z) / a; }
    real y(real x, real z) { return (d - a * x - c * z) / b; }
    real z(real x, real y) { return (d - a * x - b * y) / c; }

    // Intersection points array
    triple[] intersections;

    // Calculate intersections with x, y, z bounds
    void add_intersection(real x, real y, real z) {
        if (xmin <= x && x <= xmax && ymin <= y && y <= ymax && zmin <= z && z <= zmax) {
            intersections.push((x, y, z));
        }
    }

    // Add intersections with the six planes of the rectangular prism
    for (real y = ymin; y <= ymax; y += ymax - ymin) {
        for (real z = zmin; z <= zmax; z += zmax - zmin) {
            add_intersection(x(y, z), y, z);
        }
    }
    for (real x = xmin; x <= xmax; x += xmax - xmin) {
        for (real z = zmin; z <= zmax; z += zmax - zmin) {
            add_intersection(x, y(x, z), z);
        }
    }
    for (real x = xmin; x <= xmax; x += xmax - xmin) {
        for (real y = ymin; y <= ymax; y += ymax - ymin) {
            add_intersection(x, y, z(x, y));
        }
    }

    // Sort intersections
    intersections = sort_points(intersections);

    // Initialize plane_outline with the first intersection point
    path3 plane_outline;
    if (intersections.length > 0) {
        plane_outline = (intersections[0]);
    }

    // Convert intersections to a path
    for (int i = 1; i < intersections.length; ++i) {
        plane_outline = plane_outline -- intersections[i];
    }

    // Close the path if we have enough points
    if (intersections.length >= 3) {
        plane_outline = plane_outline -- cycle;
    }

    // Draw the outline of the clipped plane
    if (intersections.length >= 3) {
        draw(surface(plane_outline), thecolor + opacity(theopacity));
    }
}

// Test function to visualize
void draw_plane_test() {
    draw_plane((2, 2, 2), (-3, 4, 1), thecolor = red, drawthebox = true);
    draw_plane((-2, -3, 1), (-3, 4, 1), thecolor = green);
    draw_plane((-2, -3, 1), (3, 3, -1), thecolor = blue);
}

draw_plane_test();

The complete code:


unitsize(1cm);

import three;
import graph3;

// Function to sort points based on the angle with the centroid
triple[] sort_points(triple[] points) {
    triple centroid = (0, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
        centroid += points[i];
    }
    centroid /= points.length;

    real[] angles;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
        angles.push(atan2(points[i].y - centroid.y, points[i].x - centroid.x));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; ++j) {
            if (angles[i] > angles[j]) {
                real temp_angle = angles[i];
                angles[i] = angles[j];
                angles[j] = temp_angle;

                triple temp_point = points[i];
                points[i] = points[j];
                points[j] = temp_point;
            }
        }
    }

    return points;
}

void draw_plane(
    triple normal_vector
    ,triple point_on_plane
    ,real xmin = -5
    ,real xmax = 5
    ,real ymin = -5
    ,real ymax = 5
    ,real zmin = -5
    ,real zmax = 5
    ,pen thecolor = white
    ,real theopacity = 0.3
    ,bool drawthebox = false
) {

    if (drawthebox) {
        draw(box((xmin,ymin,zmin), (xmax,ymax,zmax)));
    }
    
    real a = normal_vector.x;
    real b = normal_vector.y;
    real c = normal_vector.z;
    real d = dot(normal_vector, point_on_plane);

    real x(real y, real z) {
        return (((d)-((b)*(y))-((c)*(z)))/(a));
    }

    real y(real x, real z) {
        return (((d)-((a)*(x))-((c)*(z)))/(b));
    }

    real z(real x, real y) {
        return (((d)-((a)*(x))-((b)*(y)))/(c));
    }

    if (a==0 && b==0 && c==0) {
        draw(
            surface(
                (xmin,ymin,zmin) -- 
                (xmax,ymin,zmin) --
                (xmax,ymax,zmin) --
                (xmin,ymax,zmin) --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
        draw(
            surface(
                (xmin,ymin,zmax) -- 
                (xmax,ymin,zmax) --
                (xmax,ymax,zmax) --
                (xmin,ymax,zmax) --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
        draw(
            surface(
                (xmin,ymin,zmin) -- 
                (xmax,ymin,zmin) --
                (xmax,ymin,zmax) --
                (xmin,ymin,zmax) --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
        draw(
            surface(
                (xmin,ymax,zmin) -- 
                (xmax,ymax,zmin) --
                (xmax,ymax,zmax) --
                (xmin,ymax,zmax) --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
        draw(
            surface(
                (xmin,ymin,zmin) -- 
                (xmin,ymax,zmin) --
                (xmin,ymax,zmax) --
                (xmin,ymin,zmax) --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
        draw(
            surface(
                (xmax,ymin,zmin) -- 
                (xmax,ymax,zmin) --
                (xmax,ymax,zmax) --
                (xmax,ymin,zmax) --
                cycle
            )
            ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
        );
    }

    // yz planes
    if (a!=0 && b==0 &&c==0) {
        if (xmin<=d/a && d/a<=xmax) {
            draw(
                surface(
                    (x(ymin,zmin),ymin,zmin) --
                    (x(ymax,zmin),ymax,zmin) --
                    (x(ymax,zmax),ymax,zmax) --
                    (x(ymin,zmax),ymin,zmax) --
                    cycle
                )
                ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
            );
        }
    }

    // xz planes
    if (a==0 & b!=0 & c==0) {
        if (ymin<=d/b && d/b<=ymax) {
            draw(
                surface(
                    (xmin,y(xmin,zmin),zmin) --
                    (xmax,y(xmax,zmin),zmin) --
                    (xmax,y(xmax,zmax),zmax) --
                    (xmin,y(xmin,zmax),zmax) --
                    cycle
                )
                ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
            );
        }
    }

    // xy planes
    if (a==0 && b==0 & c!=0) {
        if (zmin<=d/c && d/c<=zmax) {
            draw(
                surface(
                    (xmin,ymin,z(xmin,ymin)) --
                    (xmax,ymin,z(xmax,ymin)) --
                    (xmax,ymax,z(xmax,ymax)) --
                    (xmin,ymax,z(xmin,ymax)) --
                    cycle
                )
                ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
            );
        }
    }

    // y of x planes (invariant over z)
    if (a!=0 && b!=0 && c==0) {
        real xylower = xmin;
        if (ymax < y(xmin,0)) {
            xylower = x(ymax,0);
        }
        if (y(xmin,0) < ymin) {
            xylower = x(ymin,0);
        }

        real xyupper = xmax;
        if (ymax < y(xmax,0)) {
            xyupper = x(ymax,0);
        }
        if (y(xmax,0) < ymin) {
            xylower = x(ymin,0);
        }

        if (!(xylower<xmin || xmax<xylower) && !(xyupper<xmin || xmax<xyupper)) {
            draw(
                surface(
                    (xylower,y(xylower,0),zmin) --
                    (xyupper,y(xyupper,0),zmin) --
                    (xyupper,y(xyupper,0),zmax) --
                    (xylower,y(xylower,0),zmax) --
                    cycle
                )
                ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
            );
        }
    }

    // z of x planes (invariant over y)
    if (a!=0 && b==0 && c!=0) {
        real xzlower = xmin;
        if (z(xmin,0)<zmin) {
            xzlower = x(0,zmin);
        }
        if (zmax<z(xmin,0)) {
            xzlower = x(0,zmax);
        }

        real xzupper = xmax;
        if (z(xmax,0)<zmin) {
            xzupper = x(0,zmin);
        }
        if (zmax<z(xmax,0)) {
            xzupper = x(0,zmax);
        }

        if (!(xzlower<xmin || xzlower>xmax) && !(xzupper<xmin || xzupper>xmax)) {
            draw(
                surface(
                    (xzlower,ymin,z(xzlower,0)) --
                    (xzupper,ymin,z(xzupper,0)) --
                    (xzupper,ymax,z(xzupper,0)) --
                    (xzlower,ymax,z(xzlower,0)) --
                    cycle
                )
                ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
            );
        }
    }

    // z of y planes (invariant over x)
    if (a==0 && b!=0 && c!=0) {
        real yzlower = ymin;
        if (z(0,ymin)<zmin) {
            yzlower = y(0,zmin);
        }
        if (zmax<z(0,ymin)) {
            yzlower = y(0,zmax);
        }

        real yzupper = ymax;
        if (z(0,ymax)<zmin) {
            yzupper = y(0,zmin);
        }
        if (zmax<z(0,ymax)) {
            yzupper = y(0,zmax);
        }

        if (!(yzlower<ymin || yzlower>ymax) && !(yzupper<ymin || yzupper>ymax)) {
            draw(
                surface(
                    (xmin,yzlower,z(0,yzlower)) --
                    (xmin,yzupper,z(0,yzupper)) --
                    (xmax,yzupper,z(0,yzupper)) --
                    (xmax,yzlower,z(0,yzlower)) --
                    cycle
                )
                ,thecolor+opacity(theopacity)
            );
        }
    }

    // Intersection points array
    triple[] intersections;

    // Calculate intersections with x, y, z bounds
    void add_intersection(real x, real y, real z) {
        if (xmin <= x && x <= xmax && ymin <= y && y <= ymax && zmin <= z && z <= zmax) {
            intersections.push((x, y, z));
        }
    }

    // Add intersections with the six planes of the rectangular prism
    for (real y = ymin; y <= ymax; y += ymax - ymin) {
        for (real z = zmin; z <= zmax; z += zmax - zmin) {
            add_intersection(x(y, z), y, z);
        }
    }
    for (real x = xmin; x <= xmax; x += xmax - xmin) {
        for (real z = zmin; z <= zmax; z += zmax - zmin) {
            add_intersection(x, y(x, z), z);
        }
    }
    for (real x = xmin; x <= xmax; x += xmax - xmin) {
        for (real y = ymin; y <= ymax; y += ymax - ymin) {
            add_intersection(x, y, z(x, y));
        }
    }

    // Sort intersections
    intersections = sort_points(intersections);

    // Initialize plane_outline with the first intersection point
    path3 plane_outline;
    if (intersections.length > 0) {
        plane_outline = (intersections[0]);
    }

    // Convert intersections to a path
    for (int i = 1; i < intersections.length; ++i) {
        plane_outline = plane_outline -- intersections[i];
    }

    // Close the path if we have enough points
    if (intersections.length >= 3) {
        plane_outline = plane_outline -- cycle;
    }

    // Draw the outline of the clipped plane
    if (intersections.length >= 3) {
        draw(surface(plane_outline), thecolor + opacity(theopacity));
    }
}

void draw_plane_test() {

    // (a==0 && b==0 && c==0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,0,0)
    //     ,(0,0,0)
    //     ,thecolor=blue
    //     ,theopacity=0.1
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );

    // (a!=0 && b==0 && c==0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (-2,0,0)
    //     ,(-1,-1,-1)
    //     ,thecolor=red
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (3,0,0)
    //     ,(3,2,1)
    //     ,thecolor=red
    // );

    // (a==0 && b!=0 && c==0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,2,0)
    //     ,(2,-2,2)
    //     ,thecolor=blue
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,-3,0)
    //     ,(1,5,2)
    //     ,thecolor=blue
    // );

    // (a==0 && b==0 && c!=0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,0,1)
    //     ,(2,-2,2)
    //     ,thecolor=green
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,0,-2)
    //     ,(1,5,1)
    //     ,thecolor=green
    // );

    // (a!=0 && b!=0 && c==0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (1,2,0)
    //     ,(3,3,3)
    //     ,thecolor=red
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (-1,2,0)
    //     ,(3,3,3)
    //     ,thecolor=red
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (20,-3,0)
    //     ,(-3,-2,-4)
    //     ,thecolor=red
    // );

    // (a!=0 && b==0 && c!=0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (-2,0,3)
    //     ,(0,0,0)
    //     ,thecolor=green
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (-4,0,-3)
    //     ,(2,2,2)
    //     ,thecolor=green
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (4,0,30)
    //     ,(-2,3,-2)
    //     ,thecolor=green
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );

    // (a==0 && b!=0 && c!=0)
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,-2,3)
    //     ,(0,0,0)
    //     ,thecolor=blue
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,-4,-3)
    //     ,(2,2,2)
    //     ,thecolor=blue
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );
    // draw_plane(
    //     (0,4,30)
    //     ,(3,-2,-2)
    //     ,thecolor=blue
    //     ,drawthebox=true
    // );

    // (a!=0 && b!=0 && c!=0)
    draw_plane(
        (2,2,2)
        ,(-3,4,1)
        ,thecolor=red
        ,drawthebox=true
    );
    draw_plane(
        (-2,-3,1)
        ,(-3,4,1)
        ,thecolor=green
    );
    draw_plane(
        (-2,-3,1)
        ,(3,3,-1)
        ,thecolor=blue
    );
}

draw_plane_test();

